Question on Abel's summation formula

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence of complex numbers and $f(t)$ is a continuously differentiable function on $[1, x]$. Set
$$
A(t)=\sum_{n \leq t} a_n .
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} a_n f(n)=A(x) f(x)-\int_1^x A(t) f^{\prime}(t) d t
$$

In the proof there is this step:
$$
A(x) f(x)-\sum_{n \leq x-1} A(n) \int_n^{n+1} f^{\prime}(t) d t=A(x) f(x)-\sum_{n \leq x-1} \int_n^{n+1} A(t) f^{\prime}(t) d t.
$$
What happened there? How can you put $A(n)$ in the integral?

this is not summation by parts https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

$A(t) = \sum_{n\le t} a_n$ is a step function that is constant on every interval between two consecutive integers. Since $n<t<n+1$ inside the integral, we deduce that $A(t) = A(n)$ for all such $t$.
